# finding f(1), given f((2x-1)/(x-3)) = 4x+7

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am getting ready for a university test, and I have to brush up my mathematics (meaning back to the basics). I have been stuck with this oh so  simple thing for 2 days:

$ f((2x-1)/(x-3)) = 4x+7 $

$ f(1)=? $

I have found f(1)=8, but it seems the answer is 23. I have the same problem with other similar equations, so I must have missed something essential.
Can someone point me to the proper resource, or walk me through the whole thing?

Thanks.

EDIT

I'm working on a booklet that provides the answers, the particular answer to that particular question is given as 23 which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Let $y = (2x-1)/(x-3)$, solve for $x$ and substitute into $4x+7$ to get an expression of the form $f(y) = \dots$. Then evaluate at $y = 1$.

Comment: @FelixTheCat If you find any of the answers below useful, you should give them an upvote. You can also "accept" one of them by clicking the check mark, to let other users know that this question has been satisfactorily addressed. (Some people give preference to the first helpful answer, while others prefer to accept the best answer, regardless of chronology. You should choose a philosophy of acceptance that makes sense to you!) You can also comment on answers, if you wish to thank people.

Comment: @ Cameron Buie I did just that yesterday, though it did not appear to have been taken into account. Corrected just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x' = \frac{2x-1}{x-3}$, then

$$\begin{align*}
x'(x-3) &= 2x-1\\
x'x - 3x' &= 2x - 1\\
x'x - 2x &= 3x' - 1\\
(x'-2)x &= 3x' - 1\\
x &= \frac{3x'-1}{x'-2}
\end{align*}$$

The question is to find $f(1)$, which is to find an $x$ such that $1=\frac{2x-1}{x-3}$. Substitute $x' = 1$ to above:

$$\begin{align*}
x &= \frac{3\cdot 1 - 1}{1-2} = -2\\
f(1) &= f\left(\frac{2(-2)-1}{-2-3}\right)\\
&=4(-2) +7\\
&= -1
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{2x-1}{x-3}=1$$ for $x=-2$.

Thus, $f(1)=4\cdot(-2)+7=-1.$

Answer (score 0):

Put $x=-2$ in the given equation to obtain:
$f(\frac{2\cdot(-2)-1}{-2-3})=f(1)$

So put $x=-2$ in the right hand side of your equation to get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there may have been a typo. Had the equation been $$f\left(\frac{2x-1}{x+3}\right)=4x+7,$$ then letting $x=4$ would've given us $f(1)=23,$ as stated.

One way we can go about this is to do a change of variables, say by letting $$y=\frac{2x-1}{x-3},$$ so that $$(x-3)y=2x-1\\xy-3y=2x-1\\xy-2x=3y-1\\x(y-2)=3y-1\\x=\frac{3y-1}{y-2}.$$

Consequently, substitution into the original equation gives us $$f(y)=4\cdot\frac{3y-1}{y-2}+7\\f(y)=\frac{12y-4}{y-2}+\frac{7y-14}{y-2}\\f(y)=\frac{19y-18}{y-2}.$$

At that point, letting $y=1$ gives us $f(1)=-1$ as the answer to the problem (as written).

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, it's a typo. A typo that gave me a headache.